# JavaCV IplImage.createFrom hangs in place

Tags: image, opencv, javacv, template-matching

Not sure why this is happening. The method :

```
IplImage.createFrom(image);
```

Is hanging without returning any value. I've tried multiple images, and confirmed their existence. I'm writing an application that harnesses template matching, however this initial step is giving me a headache. Does anyone know why this method would suspend the thread and not return any value? I've done some research, and confirmed my OpenCV path is set up, and that all my libraries are properly setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before converting a `BufferedImage` to `iplimage` we need to create an `iplimage` which has same height and width as the `BufferedImage`. Try this code:

```
IplImage ipl_image = IplImage.create(buffered_image.getWidth(),buffered_.getHeight(),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
ipl_image = IplImage.createFrom(buffered_image);
```

Comment: Hi Lucas , to get the correct IPL_DEPTH from buffered_image what should i do?